# Vue3: deep reactivity

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

So I have a very simple scenario that I cannot make it work ([find the code in the vue playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNpNj72OwyAQhF9ljyY56WRfnSO55B3SGReYrCMUDIgfN8jvHsCKk2Y1q+GbHRK5WNvMEcmBUC+ctAE8hmhPTMvJGhcggcPxJw8ugpwRFhidmWCXoR3TTAujfYCb9HxQeINjeb4fufL4/ff2J9SxemsK7frTvmMaIJUBG3/YVDNzFbG4Sx59CaPtWjGXy0vAySoeMG8ANSq92KUgQIcYgtFwFkqKx5GRj5JfL81I5QGu5n5X9R5tV3ALpoOrOqXyje63/28+L9F2q0KWJ0OWdVc=))

```
<script setup>
import { ref, reactive } from 'vue'

const disabled = ref(false);

const menu = reactive<[]>([
  {
    disabled: disabled.value
  }
 ]);
</script>

<template>
  
  {{disabled}}
  <button @click="disabled = !disabled">
    Toggle
  </button>
  
  <br>
  {{menu[0]?.disabled}}
</template>
```

what am I doing wrong? why menu?[0].disabled is not reactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, reactive } from 'vue'

const disabled = ref(false);

const menu = reactive([
  {
    disabled
  }
 ]);
</script>

<template>
  
  {{disabled}}
  <button @click="disabled = !disabled">
    Toggle
  </button>
  
  <br>
  {{menu[0]?.disabled}}
</template>
```

[Сode in the vue playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNpNjstuwyAQRX/llk1SqYq7bkkf/9BdyMIm4wgVA4JxNsj/XsCqk80VV8OZOVl8h3C4zSTehEw6msBIxHP4UM5MwUdGRqTxpUSv2dwIC8boJ+wKtFNOOe1dYlxM6gdLFxzr9/3Y20TP7/f5RG5us3XL/qQckGtgY2tbSpwrKLtVp4iUwjQF2zOVBjQ0/1NLRSCHmdk7fGlr9O9RiQehp+2AaDzw469XS43rVnBbLIfY3jlX5dPr+fPweEl2m4pY/gA+PG5I)

[Docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref-unwrapping-in-reactive-objects)

Answer (score 2):

`disabled` is passed by value in setup block, there is no way how `menu` could be associated with `disabled` this way, that `disabled.value === false` makes this efficiently the same as:

```
const menu = reactive<[]>([{ disabled: false }]);
```

It should be:

```
const menu = reactive<[]>([{ disabled }]);
```

A ref is unwrapped when used inside reactive object, `menu[0].disabled === disabled.value`.

Comment: but this example was simplified... my actual goal is to make menu button disabled when something is loading... and I know when it's loading from the state's store.... so in my case would even be more complicated.... like   `disabled = appStore.isLocading` .... so is there a way of making the menu (with it's properties) reactive?

Comment: Please, make the code reflect your case then. It's possible but it's unclear from the description how it should work. It's unclear why `menu` should be mixed with another state. If its visibility depends on store property then use that property. Basically there are two ways to make `menu` react to other reactive values - a computed or a watcher.

Comment: Don't want to be rude... but I cannot post my my whole code base and hope for someone to decipher what it is? I made it as easy and straight forward as possible to illustrate the problem.... the `const disabled = ref(false);` can be whatever (a value from a pinia store in my case, or something completely different.... point is, it is reactive and when this value gets updated, the menu item does not, even though I used `reactive` to ensure deep object reactivity

Comment: That's right, that's why there's a requirement for https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for code-related questions, this is actually in SO rules. If the code doesn't reflect your problem, only you know what it really means. If it's a value from pinia then it could be `const { disabled } = storeToRefs(appStore)`, in case you wanted to know how the solution applies to a store, but it's still unclear why it should be in `menu` and how it would work if there are multiple menu items

Comment: there are multiple menu items, and it is irrelevant... the only thing I want to know... is how can the menu item update, when the dynamic (reactive) value inside changes, it is irrelevant where it comes from and how many other items there are. In other words... the example I provided it is not working... I want to know, how to make it work... it is super simple

Comment: If that's what you wanted to know then it's what the post shows. And FWIW, the accepted answer shows *exactly* the same thing but lacks the explanation, I'm not sure what confused you here.

Comment: Isn't this the same answer as the accepted one, only posted sooner, with a decent explanation and without being a code-dump answer? What am I missing? 1+